# Contracts will not compile using truffle with the "emit" keyword included in front of events

Tags: contract-development, truffle, events, error, truffle-compile

I notice there has been changes made to solidity and that the word `emit` is now to be used in front of event triggers (to distinguish from functions being called).

However when I include these in contracts using the truffle framework to compile I get an error

```
PS D:\Programming\Solidity\ICO REDO> truffle compile
Error parsing D:\Programming\Solidity\ICO REDO\contracts\Token.sol: ParsedContract.sol:75:22: ParserError: Expected token Semicolon got 'LParen'
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
```

Does anyone know why this is, or how I can get these contracts to compile with the emit word being used or should I just omit it and move on (is this now bad practice?)?

The code is:

```
function Token() public {
        Ownable(msg.sender);
        balances[msg.sender] = TOTALSUPPLY; 
        emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, TOTALSUPPLY); 
    }
```

Comment: Is there a semicolon missing from the line above it? Can you show us more of the code?

Comment: I don't think so. I have added the code to the original question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid that truffle is still using the old solc compiler, that's why you get that error. Indeed

```
$ truffle version
Truffle v4.1.3 (core: 4.1.3) //this is the last truffle version
Solidity v0.4.19 (solc-js)
```

You can try to update solc manually and the issue will be fixed.

```
$ cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle
$ npm install solc@0.4.21
```

this will update your solc version and eventually you're able to compile your code correctly.

**note:** This will work for Mac, in Windows you might need to update the compiler in another folder
**note2:** in case you're using an older truffle version I suggest to update it